# How to use Knockout binding handlers in Aurelia?

Tags: knockout.js, aurelia

I have a project written in Durandal and Knockout. I would like to upgrade Durandal to Aurelia and keep Knockout as it is. I would like to know how to use Knockout binding handlers in Aurelia (`ko.bindingHandlers`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plug-in (https://github.com/code-chris/aurelia-knockout) to keep knockout in an Aurelia project.

Check this page for more details:
https://github.com/code-chris/aurelia-knockout/wiki

Comment: I am using aurelia-knockout only, but knockout binding handlers are not working